# Why an AccessDenied error on S3 files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

Some of the files uploaded on S3 can't be read because of an `AccessDenied` error. It was working well so far...

## Gemfile

```
ruby '2.2.0'
gem 'rails', '3.2.22.2'
gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
gem 'sprockets', '2.2.3'
gem 'carrierwave', '0.11.0'
gem 'fog', '1.38.0', require: 'fog/aws'
```

## carrierwave.rb

```
if Rails.env.test?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = false
  end
else
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :fog
    config.fog_credentials = {
      provider: Figaro.env.fog_provider,
      aws_access_key_id: Figaro.env.fog_aws_access_key_id,
      aws_secret_access_key: Figaro.env.fog_aws_secret_access_key,
      region: Figaro.env.fog_region,
    }

    config.fog_directory  = "mycompany-#{Rails.env}"
    config.fog_public     = true
    config.fog_attributes = { 'Cache-Control' => "max-age=#{365.days.to_i}" }
    config.permissions = 0666
  end
end
```

## URL I'm trying to reach:

https://mycompany-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/coaching/attachment/1735/File-Uploaded-0001.pdf

## The error AWS give me:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>12D13432D83CD9DE</RequestId>
    <HostId>
        SKLsZ20cJ4x2uxxIR/6ejZ6w6rpbH9HU18+22Sm6/sr+t1mVwe8+zWpe+lFl0v05GMU0TWtcNOI=
    </HostId>
</Error>
```

How can I set the `Read-Only` attribute on some folders? AWS S3 allow me to "Make the folder public" but I don't want that.

Thank you

Comment: Look at bucket policies. Refer this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-iam-policies.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since AWS has changed I don't know how to set and where to set an ACL READ-ONLY for Anonymous users. `{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: A 'public folder' in this context is publicly-readable, not writable. You would have to explicitly add permission to make it writable.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do I need to change my Ruby code? Or does the edit must be "Amazon side"?